# What is the reason html showing variable names client side in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, html

My application does contains below data

```
     "countries = [
          {locale:'en-US',name:'United States'},
          {locale:'en-GB',name:'United Kingdom'},
          {locale:'en-FR',name:'France'}]"
```

And I have written html code

```
       <li ng-repeat = "country in countries">
          {{ 'Country: ' + country.name + ', Locale: ' + country.locale }}
       </li>
```

As a output it is showing:

```
  List of Countries with locale:
```

home.html file

```
<html>   
 <head>
    <title>AngularJS First Application</title>
 </head>
 <script src =   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
 </script>

 <body>
  <div ng-app = "" ng-init= "countries:[
      {locale:'en-GB',name:'United Kingdom'},
      {locale:'en-US',name:'United State'},
      {locale:'en-FR',name:'France'}]; quantity = 1;cost = 30;" >

  <p>List of Countries with locale:</p>

  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat = "country in countries">
     {{ 'Country: ' + country.name + ', Locale: ' + country.locale }}
    </li>
  </ol>   
 </div> 
 </body>

</html>
```

Why it is not showing countries name in list?

Comment: There are no script tags in that page. Must include `angular.js` and your application module code

Comment: I updated with script tag. It is not showing list of countries.

Comment: did you check browser console for errors? likely getting a parse error thrown that would be a good clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your ng-init....

you have:

```
<div ng-app = "" ng-init= "countries:[ 
  {locale:'en-GB',name:'United Kingdom'},
  {locale:'en-US',name:'United State'},
  {locale:'en-FR',name:'France'}]; quantity = 1;cost = 30;" >
```

where it should be:

```
// changed countries:[
// to: countries=[
<div ng-app = "" ng-init= "countries=[
  {locale:'en-GB',name:'United Kingdom'},
  {locale:'en-US',name:'United State'},
  {locale:'en-FR',name:'France'}]; quantity = 1;cost = 30;" >
```

Working **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0cYEm0L1QTfvJUttfrch?p=preview)**